# How to checkout certain branch

Tags: git

I cloned my repository with

`git --branch master https://myresository`

for optimising XXL repository download size. I have dozens of remote branches, so I only cloned the one I wanted.

Now I also want branch2 locally. Can I somehow append download only that certain branch?

Comment: Do you mean `git clone --single-branch -b master <url>`?

Comment: @torek, I think, that means the same, though the exact command text was as in the question.

Comment: `git --branch` produces `unknown option: --branch` and does not make a clone.

Answer (score -1):

you can create branch from your local repository, with: git checkout -b 'branchname', this command create branch with your changes in local, but if you want move to other branch created in remote repository you can switch the branch with: git checkout 'branchname', if you want download other branch in remote repository you can use: git clone --branch 'branchname' remote-repo-url

I wish this can help you: [how to download specific branch](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/como-clonar-una-branch-en-git/)